# How to redirect non www to www on Digital Ocean Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, certbot

I'm hosted on Digital Ocean Ubuntu server.

I want to redirect my non-www traffic to www. All using https.

Here's what I have for /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
    if ($host = www.test.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = test.com) {
        return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name test.com www.test.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

However, it's not working. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use 'if' to listen for requests. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

The Nginx manual for setting up servers: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/

Here's an example to match your setup:

```
# catch all traffic to https://www.test.com
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.test.com;

    #change this to your web root
    root /home/test; 

    # specify index files
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    #change this to your certificate paths and so on
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    #this will look for a file, then a directory, finally for an index file, leave as is
    location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    #change this to match your php setup
    location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}

# redirect all https traffic from non www tot www, you need a certificate here    
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name test.com;
    return 301 https://www.test.com$request_uri;

    #change this to your certificate paths 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;
}

# redirect all traffic from http to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.test.com test.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: How can I change my code to fit?

Comment: I will add some comments to make it more clear

Comment: e.g. use this tutorial for your https setup: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Elaborated the answer some more, does it make sense to you?